# Failure to update conda

Tags: python, conda

if I try to use conda to update python packages or do "conda update conda", I get the following error message:

```
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.binstar.org/rsignell/linux-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),),)
```

I have conda 4.3.30 installed. Is this likely to be a temporary issue or does something need to be fixed for me to be able to update packages?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this as an issue at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7365 and the solution was to do:

```
conda config --remove channels 'https://conda.binstar.org/rsignell'
```